# Jinja2 Using images in HTML

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I wasted a lot of time to find out what is wrong. I need your help now.
I want to render template with image from my filesystem. But it is not working.
Path - string that contains file name

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():

    return render_template('main.html',image = path)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2></h2>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/uploader">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
<img src={{ url_for('static', filename = image) }} >//i can't figure how to change this to use {{image}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there an image saved in your code's `static/` directory with the name in `path`?

Comment: Yes. Path contains the name of an image

Comment: I can't figure out, how I can use something beautiful like {{image}}

Answer (score 3):

Just generate full image path in your view and pass it to your template

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    #path is filename string
    image_file = url_for('static', filename=path)

    return render_template('main.html', image_file=image_file)
```

and then just use it as full link

```
<img src={{ image_file}} >
```

if you have image file (with filename which stored in `path`) in your static folder this should work

Answer (score 1):

If you was set the static folder like that (or other methods):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():

    return render_template('main.html', image = url_for("static", filename=path))
```

or shorter:

```
    return render_template('main.html', image='/static/' + path))
```

after you will put your image in `/static` folder you can get it from template:

```
<img src="{{image)}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='image') }}">
```

Where 'image' refers to the path of the image file inside static folder. Make sure to use the full name of image file along with its file type i.e. jpg, png etc.

Comment: it is wrong solution: inside `{{ ... }}` tag you can just get your variable name, like filename=image. do **not** use `'{{'` again